# If Harry was entered into a tournament of 3 schools, under a fourth school, why was he not rejected?

Tags: harry-potter

I've just read [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22621/3804) question, which highlights how the goblet was fooled.

But why do the teachers allow it? DVK makes the analogy that it is like a program with a bug. But if a bug presents an obviously incorrect output, why not just ignore it?

I remember the headmasters and headmistresses discussing it, and concluding harry should compete... but I can't remember or fathom why they wouldn't dismiss the result (or at least Harry).

Comment: Perhaps of interest/related: [What happens when a Triwizard contestant refused to participate?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17373/what-happens-when-a-triwizard-contestant-refuses-to-participate). FWIW, I know of no canon quote that says the contestants will die if they refuse to participate -- I would love to see that quote, though, if anyone knows of its existence. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - Since dlanod's answer seems to heavily mirror mine, is this not a dupe?

Comment: @Richard is argue that my question is focused on the teachers disavowing the tournament not the participants changing their minds.  Let me read that question again.

Comment: I think the second part of my answer to this question is related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72485/3567 but that's why Dumbledore kept Harry in, not the other teachers/officials.

Answer (score 6):

### Harry has to compete because if he doesn't, he'll die (probably).

In what can only be described as the stupidest plot-twist ever, it turns out that in a competition designed to be entered by children, the Goblet is set to mete out a severe punishment to anyone who refuses to take part.

My reading was that since competing in the competition (the first task of which involves facing a giant man-eating dragon) is the *lesser* danger, this punishment must be either  **deadly** or **mind-destroying**:

> ‘Finally, I wish to impress upon any of you wishing to compete that
>   this Tournament is not to be entered into lightly. **Once a champion has
>   been selected by the Goblet of Fire, he or she is obliged to see the
>   Tournament through to the end. The placing of your name in the Goblet
>   constitutes a binding, magical contract. There can be no change of
>   heart once you have become champion.** Please be very sure, therefore,
>   that you are whole-heartedly prepared to play, before you drop your
>   name into the Goblet

It appears that the three heads lack the ability to change or cancel the results, even if the Goblet throws a wobbly:

> Bagman wiped his round, boyish face with his handkerchief and looked
>   at Mr Crouch, who was standing outside the circle of the firelight,
>   his face half hidden in shadow. He looked slightly eerie, the half
>   darkness making him look much older, giving him an almost skull-like
>   appearance. When he spoke, however, it was in his usual curt voice.
>   **‘We must follow the rules, and the rules state clearly that those people whose names come out of the Goblet of Fire are bound to compete
>   in the Tournament.’**

and

> ‘Empty threat, Karkaroff,’ growled a voice from near the door. ‘You
>   can’t leave your champion now. He’s got to compete. **They’ve all got to
>   compete. Binding magical contract, like Dumbledore said. Convenient,
>   eh?’**

and

> Don’t you?’ said Moody quietly. ‘It’s very simple, Karkaroff. **Someone
>   put Potter’s name in that Goblet knowing he’d have to compete if it
>   came out.’**

Comment: Can you provide the citation from *Goblet of Fire* that verifies Triwizard contests who don't/refuse to compete will die? I don't recall that.

Comment: @Slytherincess - I assumed he'd die. But having read the answers [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20183/20774) I'm not now convinced. Clearly there are consequences...

Comment: @Richared -- Definitely agree with you that there would be (likely fairly dire) consequences. :)

Comment: This spell comes to mind: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spells_in_Harry_Potter#.28Unbreakable_Vow.29

Comment: @Pureferret - That's what I was thinking. It's the only other "magical contract" we see in the books.